# Error: No matching files were found with search pattern: D:\a\1\s\**\*.apk

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have **react-native** application in windows 10 which works great in my development machine, it can release **signed apk** and everything is ok.

I am using VSTS (TFS Online) as my source control, When I Build my project, everything built successfully, but I get strange error

this is where you can see build successfully done, and I face error
[image]

this is the error details
[image]

any clue?

**Update**
These are my tasks in Build definition

[image: all tasls view]
[image: Sign apk view]
[image: Copy files view]

**Update 2**

Add Gradlew task in Build definition

[image: gradlew task view]

Comment: Can you attach a photo of the task? (in the build definition)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I updated question, with 3 photos of different build definition tasks. not to mention that I didn't add any variable to this definition.

Comment: @NasserIt looks like the Gradle build not made the apk file, can you upload also the Gradle task log?

Comment: @NasserHadjloo How did you define `build.gradle` file under the `app` directory? Check this blog to see whether it helps you: https://medium.com/@arkilis/using-gradle-3-0-to-create-your-debug-apk-from-command-line-c39f18598709

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I can get apk from command prompt, the problem is in VSTS, not in my PC

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I updated the question with gradlew build view, I didn't change anything and every setting is in its default condition. to give you more info, I changed the JDK to version 8, (which I am using locally) and nothing changed, so currently I am using the default JDK

Comment: @NasserHadjloo I've tried a project with default Android build template and got a successful build. I'd like to share my project to you, do you need it?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT may I share my project with you, so that you can check what is wrong? may I have your email to add you to the team?

Comment: @NasserHadjloo Due to company's policy, we are not able to provide email address, could you create a test project and share it to some public platform?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I changed the working directory to android, and the problem has been solved, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question for those who may face similar issue

Based on the @Cece-Don-MSFT helps, I found out that in the gradlew task I had to change the working directory

despit the fact that in most cases this variable should be empty, because it is set to the project root, in my case, I had to change the working directory to android directory

Comment: I am facing same issue, can you please tell me how you changed the directory?