# Appcenter can't find APK file

Tags: android, xamarin, build, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I have this weird error, I've been using appcenter for a long time, but never experienced this.
I setup a build with appcenter which fetches from azure devops repo. The application is a Xamarin.Android native application. Once I run the build, everything goes well. Untill the signin step. When the step is about to start, I get this error:

`##[error]No matching files were found with search pattern: /Users/runner/work/1/s/**/*.apk`

Looks like the APK was not found, though the build runs successfully without error.
Please I need your help to figure out a solution to this issue.

Comment: Did you perhaps switch to Android App Bundle (aab) instead?

Comment: Can you please have a try with the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692776/error-no-matching-files-were-found-with-search-pattern-d-a-1-s-apk)?

Comment: @Cheesebaron you mean in my android project ?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I'm in Xamarin.Android, I don't use gradle, but the solution mentions I should change the gradle working directory. Is there an equivalent in Xamarin Android ?

Comment: Yes, I think it's the same.

Comment: In your csproj file for the Android Application project. Check whether `<AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>` is set to `apk` or `aab`. If it is `aab` then you need to change the search pattern to search for `/**/*.aab` instead.

Comment: Thanks it was set to aab. Please, how do I change this search pattern ? there is no means to configure the yml buils in appcenter

Comment: @Cheesebaron I succeeded by switching the toggle for "build aab" in the build configuration settings. Thanks again. You can write your answer below and I'll approve it as the accepted answer if you wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your csproj file for the Android Application project. Check whether `<AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>` is set to `apk` or `aab`. If it is `aab` then you need to change the search pattern to search for `/**/*.aab` instead. Otherwise, it will be looking for stuff that wasn't produced during the build.

To change the search path of appcenter, go to your build configurations and toggle the switch with label: “Build android app bundle”.

Answer (score 0):

the change `<AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>` for  `<AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>` works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing Android Apps and publishing them through Play Store, starting August 2021, new apps are required to target API level 30 (Android 11) and use the **Android App Bundle publishing format**. (aab)

If you want to know more about the Android App Bundle publishing format, [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) you have more information. As Cheesebaron is mentioning, if you are using AppCenter for building and packaging your Apps, just use the flag "Build App Bundle" in the Build configuration

[image]